# Unity 3d player jump does't work, rb.addforce doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have a very basic `infinite runner` and I want to make my player jump. I have attached `rigidbody` to my player, have instantiated it. here is some part of my code

```
 void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (OnGround)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        { 
            rBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 10, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("jump");
            OnGround = false;
        }
    } 
}     

void onCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log("collision");
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        OnGround = true;
    }
}
```

I have tried to put this part in `Update()`, no result.
The interesting part is that `Debug.Log("jump")` shows on the console, but the player doesn't want to jump.
Method `void CollisonOther()` is never called.
I have also tried to change `velocity` and use `transform.translate`, no result

jump. How can I make it jump?

Comment: It's difficult to say what is wrong. The code looks correct. Some things to check: The `Rigidbody` must not be kinematic and active. What is its mass? Perhaps the characters position is set from other code? What happens if you increase the force?

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoints and [debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` starts with a **capital `O`** otherwise it is never called! could this be the issue?

Comment: OnCollisionEnter is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider, if you dont have a collider/rigidbody attached to the collision object it wont thrigger.

Comment: As a sidenote, it's recommended to make all `Input` calls within the flow of the `Update` method. See [the `Input` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) for more information.

Comment: @aalmigthy yes, the rigid body is not kinematic and active. mass is 1 and the player itself is very small

Comment: @derHugo thanks for reply, i tried. but it seems that the function should work

Comment: @Maria10 Check the `Rigidbody`s `Constraints`. Is there anything freeezed? Also: Any errors on the console? Your class is a `MonoBehaviour` subclass?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be the issue.  Make sure the isKinematic box is unchecked.  It's also possible that the character is jumping but you cannot see it if your sprites were imported too big (ie: it's jumping a very very small amount relative to the size).  You could try printing some more debug statements of the character's position to see if it is actually changing or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really can't jump: I have checked the position, also everything is okay with the rigid body, it is not kinematic.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be correct in your code but don't know why not jumping. BTW, you can try with this code 
just without AddForce and changing the checking you are using.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && OnGround)
{
    rBody.velocity = new Vector2(rBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
}
```

Make sure it is under your Update method coz Input calls in Update method. If your 'OnGround' Layer check is
perfect it should work.

Answer (score 0):

OnCollisionEnter should have a capital O instead of lower case. As written, onCollisionEnter will never be entered.

That's the only code problem that could be wrong, assuming you actually assigned the other variables corrrectly. However, there could be a variety of game object related behavior.

Is the ground tag applied to the game obejct that you think your runner is colliding with? If not, it won't jump.

Is your mass for the jumper's rigidbody very high? With the default of 1, it jumps pretty high, but could not get the right amount of force if it was a larger mass.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have corrected OnCollisionEnter Syntax. The tag for the ground is correctly assigned. I have assigned a tag for each tile which I am instantiating and making infinite ground if there can be a problem, I don't know.  Object mass is one, and the object itself is very small.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and, after hours of investigating, in my case it had nothing to do with the code, but with the below Unity bug (still present in 2020.1.6f1).

For some reason, it interfered with any key inputs I checked for in the code (in your case GetKey(KeyCode.Space)

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/urp-errors-are-constantly-thrown-when-active-input-handling-is-set-to-input-system-package

The fix was going to Edit - Project Settings - Active Input Handling - select Both.